# Inserting data of array into db

Tags: shell

I have an array consisting of around 10000 elements.
I need to insert these into a db.

I hv used a parameterized sql using a while loop over the array in korn shell.
However, this takes a lot time since it connects to db ,commits and disconnects for each element.

Can you suggest a faster way to insert the elements?

Comment: Would be nice to have more information, the script for one thing, the db type for another, etc...

Comment: you could write the data in a file and use sqlldr to load entire file at once, would probably do it in secs. But would be better if you provide more info, how you are going about it, provide code snippet as well as db info.

Comment: @rajnish thank you for the input...went about the same way using the following cat test.json | jq -r '.[] | [.serialnumber,.mac,.model| tostring] | @ csv >> stb.csv

Comment: I am stuck with adding colons in the macaddresses...can you help me doing that....i have the csv as follows   17756788934,FF2211336568,AD2200 ......i want to add a colon after every 2 characters for data in 2nd column for all rows in the csv.